# Xcode error - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:

Tags: ios, xcode, crash

i dont know where can be problem:/

```
2014-04-11 22:36:33.815 bus[1432:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<TableViewCell 0x8e63160> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key DescriptionLablel.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x017ee1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0156d8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0187dfe1 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x0122dd9e -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
    4   Foundation                          0x0119a1d7 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 88
    5   Foundation                          0x01199731 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
    6   UIKit                               0x0029c508 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) setValue:forKey:] + 168
    7   Foundation                          0x011fbb0a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412
    8   UIKit                               0x004e41f4 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
    9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0157f7de -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x017e976a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
    11  UIKit                               0x004e2d4d -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1417
    12  UIKit                               0x00319db0 -[UITableView _dequeueReusableViewOfType:withIdentifier:] + 370
    13  UIKit                               0x0031a089 -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:] + 48
    14  UIKit                               0x0031a0b9 -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 43
    15  bus                                 0x000034bf -[TableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 127
    16  UIKit                               0x0032611f -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 412
    17  UIKit                               0x003261f3 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 69
    18  UIKit                               0x00307ece -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2428
    19  UIKit                               0x0031c6a5 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 213
    20  UIKit                               0x0029c964 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    21  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0157f82b -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    22  QuartzCore                          0x03c5945a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    23  QuartzCore                          0x03c4d244 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    24  QuartzCore                          0x03c593a5 -[CALayer layoutIfNeeded] + 160
    25  UIKit                               0x0035eae3 -[UIViewController window:setupWithInterfaceOrientation:] + 304
    26  UIKit                               0x00274aa7 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 5212
    27  UIKit                               0x00273646 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 82
    28  UIKit                               0x00273518 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 117
    29  UIKit                               0x002735a0 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 67
    30  UIKit                               0x0027263a __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 120
    31  UIKit                               0x0027259c -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 400
    32  UIKit                               0x002732f3 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 870
    33  UIKit                               0x002768e6 -[UIWindow setDelegate:] + 449
    34  UIKit                               0x00350b77 -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 180
    35  UIKit                               0x0026c474 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 591
    36  UIKit                               0x0026c5ef -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 312
    37  UIKit                               0x0026c86b -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
    38  UIKit                               0x002773c8 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
    39  UIKit                               0x00227bc0 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 2097
    40  UIKit                               0x0022c667 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 824
    41  UIKit                               0x00240f92 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3517
    42  UIKit                               0x00241555 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    43  UIKit                               0x0022e250 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 683
    44  GraphicsServices                    0x037e3f02 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    45  GraphicsServices                    0x037e3a0d PurpleEventCallback + 46
    46  CoreFoundation                      0x01769ca5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    47  CoreFoundation                      0x017699db __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    48  CoreFoundation                      0x0179468c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    49  CoreFoundation                      0x017939d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    50  CoreFoundation                      0x017937eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    51  UIKit                               0x0022bd9c -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    52  UIKit                               0x0022df9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    53  bus                                 0x00003a4d main + 141
    54  libdyld.dylib                       0x01e35701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: @rmaddy - Though I've got to give him a bit of credit for actually including the entire message, vs just paraphrasing it.  Given that the critical info is at the very right end of the first long line this is extremely useful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It means that in a nib file you have an outlet called `DescriptionLablel`, but you don't have a property for it in your code.  "Label" is misspelled, so that could be your problem.