# StopWatch app keeps crashing

Tags: ios, swift

SO I'm making a simple stopwatch app via a tutorial I found online. I followed the code word for ford and created a the UI to connect to it too.
However, whenever I try to run the program it the iOS Simulator fails to get past the screen which states the name of the app. Then it produces a ton of code, and highlights this:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {`
```

under which it states `THREAD 1: signal SIGABRT`

What does that mean?

Also in the console I get this message:

(apologies in advance for the big chunk of code, tabbing it it didn't seem to work)

```
2015-06-15 15:53:54.313 stopwatch2[20524:1296474] ***   Terminating    app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:     '[<stopwatch2.ViewController 0x7f9280476960> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key display.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fcecc65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000111857bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fcec8a9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000011010ab53 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fc34d50 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    5   UIKit                               0x000000011086352b -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001106bb718 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001106bbd08 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001106bbf79 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001106bc40e -[UIViewController view] + 27
   10  UIKit                               0x00000001105d72c9 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
   11  UIKit                               0x00000001105d768f -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 247
   12  UIKit                               0x00000001105e3e21 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
   13  UIKit                               0x0000000110587457 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2732
   14  UIKit                               0x000000011058a1de -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1349
   15  UIKit                               0x00000001105890d5 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
   16  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001133675e5 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 21
   17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fc2041c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
   18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fc16165 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
   19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fc15f25 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
   20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fc15366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
   21  UIKit                               0x0000000110588b42 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
   22  UIKit                               0x000000011058b900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
   23  stopwatch2                          0x000000010faf0ff7 main + 135
   24  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111faf145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException   
(lldb)
```

However, this is my actual code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer = NSTimer()
    var count = 0
    func updateTime() {
        count++
        time.text = "\(count)"
    }

    @IBOutlet var time: UILabel!

    @IBAction func pause(sender: AnyObject) {
        timer.invalidate()
    }

    @IBAction func stop(sender: AnyObject) {
        timer.invalidate()
        count = 0
        time.text = "0"
    }

    @IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"),userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()    
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Someone please help?

Comment: try adding more tags to your question to get more attention like the programming language (swift if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: will do. Sorry about that :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key)

Comment: possible duplicate of [xcode - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '\[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:\]:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022187/xcode-terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-nsunknownkeyexception-reaso)

Answer (score 0):

You probably connected an object called `display` to your View Controller, but then removed/changed the property in the source code.

You have to go to your controller in the Storyboard, click the outlets icon and delete the `display` outlet, it will have an exclamation mark.